# routerlink always returns to ' '

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular-standalone-components

I have a problem where my `routerlink` when clicked always returns me to the '' path of *app.routes.ts*.
While the routerlinks are respectively 'user/teams' and 'user/dashboard'

I can access the pages when I go to "/user/dashboard" or "/user/teams". Only when using `routerlink` it does not direct me to the right component.

This is my router setup.

This is my *app.routes.ts*:

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './view/home/home.component';
import { UserComponent } from './shared/layouts/user/user.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '', 
    pathMatch: 'full', 
    component: HomeComponent
},
{
    path:'user',
    loadComponent: () => UserComponent,
    children: [
       {
            path:'',
            loadChildren: () => import('./view/user/user.routes').then((m) => m.routes)
       }
    ]
}
];
```

I have a second routes file *user.routes.ts*:

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { TeamsComponent } from './teams/teams.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: 'dashboard',
      loadComponent: () => DashboardComponent,
    },
    {
      path:'teams',
      loadComponent: () => TeamsComponent
    }
    ,
    {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: 'dashbaord',
    } 
];
```

Here is my *user.component.html* which contains the `<router-outlet>`.

```
<main class="d-flex flex-nowrap">
    <app-side-menu></app-side-menu>
    <div class="container-fluid p-5">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</main>
```

My side menu contains the routerlinks as follows.
The *side-menu.component.html*:

```
<li>
  <a href="#" routerlink="/user/dashboard" class="nav-link link-body-emphasis">
    <svg class="bi pe-none me-2" width="16" height="16"><use xlink:href="#speedometer2"></use></svg>
    Dashboard
  </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#" routerlink="/user/teams" class="nav-link link-body-emphasis">
    <svg class="bi pe-none me-2" width="16" height="16"><use xlink:href="#table"></use></svg>
    My Teams
  </a>
</li>
```

and this is the *side-menu.component.ts*:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-side-menu',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './side-menu.component.html',
  styleUrl: './side-menu.component.scss'
})
export class SideMenuComponent {

}
```

Hope you can help me out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Naren's answer should resolve your routing issue. For my version:

1. Use `loadChildren` instead of `children` for the `routes` in the *app.route.ts*

> app.route.ts

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'user',
    loadComponent: () => UserComponent,
    loadChildren: () => import('./view/user/user.routes').then((m) => m.routes),
  },
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: HomeComponent,
  },
];
```

> user.routes.ts

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadComponent: () => DashboardComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'teams',
    loadComponent: () => TeamsComponent,
  },
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard',
  },
];
```

2. Import the `RouterModule` in the `SideMenuComponent`.

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-side-menu',
  templateUrl: './side-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./side-menu.component.css'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterModule]
})
export class SideMenuComponent { ... }
```

3. Also there is typo error, it should be router**L**ink but not router**l**ink.

```
<li>
  <a href="#" routerLink="/user/dashboard" class="nav-link link-body-emphasis">
    ...
  </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#" routerLink="/user/teams" class="nav-link link-body-emphasis">
    ...
  </a>
</li>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-7pkcpr?file=src%2F%20app.routes.ts)

Answer (score 2):

Please update app routing to

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './view/home/home.component';
import { UserComponent } from './shared/layouts/user/user.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '', 
    pathMatch: 'full', 
    component: HomeComponent
},
{
    path:'user',
    loadChildren: () => import('./view/user/user.routes').then((m) => m.routes)
}

];
```

Could you please change the routing of users to

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { TeamsComponent } from './teams/teams.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', component: UserComponent ,children:[
    {
      path: 'dashboard',
      loadComponent: () => DashboardComponent,
    },
    {
      path:'teams',
      loadComponent: () => TeamsComponent
    }
    ,
    {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: 'dashbaord',
    }
    ]
}
];
```

Comment: Edited user.routes.ts as suggested. behaviour did not change. Still I get routed to '' of app.routes.ts

Comment: @Diceble updated my answer please ensure usercomponent has a router outlet

Comment: I updated my post as well including the html code of the user.component.html which contains the router outlet. 
I also implemented your suggested changes.
unfortunely the behaviour is still the same.